# Replacing values in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I am trying to change the following:

(Núm 1:1)
(Núm 1:2)
(Núm 1:3)
(Núm 1:4)
(Núm 1:5)
(Núm 1:6)
(Núm 1:7)
(Núm 1:8)
(Núm 1:9)
(Núm 1:10)

etc

to

NUM|1|1|
NUM|1|2|
NUM|1|3|
NUM|1|4|
NUM|1|5|
NUM|1|6|
NUM|1|7|
NUM|1|8|
NUM|1|9|
NUM|1|10|
etc

with a simple search and replace in Notepad++, instead of trying to replace each line 1 by one.  Since these are Bible scripture references, and there are thus over 31000 lines to change.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Go to find/replace panel (CTRL+F), check radio box *Regular Expression* then in *Find What* you write `\(Núm ([0-9]*):([0-9]*)\)` and in *Replace with* write `NUM|\1|\2`

I add a little explanation to *find & replace* in Notepad++ with regular expressions, so maybe can be useful to other cases similar to this.

Parenthesis in the *find field* identify a *regex* that can be referenced in the *replace field*, in this specific case the first  group `([0-9]*)` is referenced in the replace by \1, and the second ([0-9]*) by \2. In this case, external parenthesis in the find string are escaped with `\(`.

Comment: ..i've slightly modified the find part if you want to remove the parenthesis also, and to consider only numbers

Comment: ok this works but only if the second number (after :) is only 1 digit, what for numbers 10 and above, and even 100 and above? e.g Num 12:50?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in three steps (three uses of Replace tool):

`(Núm |`  to `NUM`

`:` to `|`

`)` to `|`

Easiest way to call Replace tool is to hit `Ctrl+F` and go the second tab.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but alas what i need is a bit more sophisticated.  I did what you said, but searching and replacing the : wont work.  All the bible verses are also included in the lines, and some of them also contains :.  Thus it will also change those values. :(  Is there no string I can use to fix this?

Comment: Yes, my way will work only on example you provided, not more complicated texts (you should have included them). Try obe6 answer - it's better (it will leave the outer `()` but if you understand what the regular expression used means you will be able to adjust it right or maybe you want to leave them).